# How to get error msg in videoView in android?

Tags: android, android-videoview

I have a stream link like

```
http://*****/***.m3u8
```

we have tested it both on native `VideoView` and `Vitamio` View and both could play this video nicely. But when the link has too much trafic and becomes busy Vitamio showed a dialog messaging

```
"This video can not be played"
```

but the native one failed to show any message and keeps showing tha black blank screen, as far as I did is here

```
mVideoView.setOnErrorListener(new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder(VideoViewTv.this)
                        .setTitle("Error")
                        .setMessage("Video can not be played.").setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes,new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
                        finish();
                }}).setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert).show();
return true;
});
```

but this is only being fired when I place a wrong url or something but never get called in my mentioned issue, what to do actually?